# fired local notification at specific time

Tags: swift3, nsusernotificationcenter

please i have an issue about how can i trigger the local notification at specific time ? without user trigger it and need the app at specific time fired local notification

the following my code :

this is for get permission from the user

```
func registerLocal() {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("Yay!")
        } else {
            print("D'oh")
        }
    }
}
```

// this i schedule local notification 
    func scheduleLocal() {

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Late wake up call"
    content.body = "The early bird catches the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese."
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()



    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 3
    dateComponents.minute = 19
    dateComponents.day = 3
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
     center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
}
```

// her i call theses methods

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            registerLocal()
            scheduleLocal()
         return true
  }
```

and when i close my app i have no receive the notification , please help about how can i trigger the local notification at specific time

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()` after adding your notification, since it will cancel the previously added pending notification as well. You should rather check after calling `center.addRequest(request)` whether your request has actually been added or not by

```
center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { pendingRequest in
    print("Pending notifications: \(pendingRequest)")   //Just for debugging
})
```

Or you can also specify a completion handler to `addRequest`, which will return an error if the request hasn't been added succesfully:

```
center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
   print(error)
})
```